# Accessing plugin prototype function using array square [] brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to JS and I was just going through the syntax of modal.js. Basically I have a small difficulty, a lot of classical JS plugins use the below skeleton code for the plugin:

```
var Modal = function(element , options){
    this.options = options
    this.$body = $(document.body)
    this.$element = $(element)
    this.isShown = null
    this.$backdrop = 
    this.scrollbarWidth = 0
  } 


  Modal.prototype.toggle = function (_relatedTarget) {
      // do something
  }

  Modal.prototype.show = function (_relatedTarget) {
      // do something
  }


var data = new Modal(somthing , radnom); 

                          // now if we assume that option is "show", 
                          //the show function in Modal will be executed 
                          // but my question is data is not an array, so how can we use 
                          // [] square brackets to access the properties of Modal/data ?? 
data[option](_relatedtarget);
```

Now my question is about accessing the properties of a plugin, see how a function is being called using the following syntax:

```
data[option](_relatedtarget);
```

See my comment in the code. How can we access the properties of data using `[]`; it's not an array, right?

Comment: `[]` is a property accessor operator just like `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`[]` are not just for arrays**

You can use `[]` to access properties on an object too.

You can use

- `data["show"]` to access the `show` method

OR

- `data.show` which is the same thing

---

One advantage of the `[]` is that you can use a variable within the brackets

```
var option = "show";
data[option](something); // call the `show` method on `data`
```

---

If you know the method you want to call, using the `.` is much nicer looking in the code

```
data.show(something); // much quicker (to type), and prettier
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript has arrays:

```
var anArray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
```

and associative arrays (also known as maps):

```
var anAssociativeArray = { first: "No. 1", second: 2, somethingElse: "Other" };
```

both of these data structures can be accessed via `[]`:

```
anArray[3]                  // will get the element of the array in position 3
                            // (starting counting frrom 0).
anAssociativeArray['first'] // will get the element of the associative array with the
                            // key 'first'.
```

Associative arrays can also be accessed via the `.key` notation:

```
anAssociativeArray.first    // will also get the property with key 'first'.
```

The `.` notation can be used if you know the key you want to access but if you want to dynamically select which key then you need to use the `[]` notation.

```
var whichOptionToPick = 'somethingElse';
var value = anAssociativeArray[ whichOptionToPick ]; // will get the value "Other".
```

Comment: imo, I don't think it's appropriate to call an object an "associative array" or a "map" in JavaScript